# .bat file is not executing on Linux server

Tags: linux

I've made a simple bat file "run_perl.bat" that executes a Perl script "Oncomine_main.pl" in \data\test_scripts directory.

Here is the content of the bat file:

```
cd /data/test_scripts
perl Oncomine_main.pl
```

I run the script from the login directory

Here is what is returned to me:

```
[username@path-twood3 ~]$ ./run_perl.bat
: No such file or directory /data/test_scripts
": No such file or directorymine_main.pl
```

Please suggest how to fix this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Most people would not call that a batch file since you are not using Microsoft Windows and cmd.exe.  It's usually called a shell script, and you should have a ".sh" extension on it or no extension.

Answer (score 1):

Add `#!/bin/sh` as the first line of run_perl.bat.

Comment: i get `-bash: ./run_perl.bat: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` after I've added #!/bin/sh.

Comment: run_perl.bat has DOS-style line endings (\r\n) instead of UNIX-style line endings (\n). Use `dos2unix run_perl.bat` to fix this. You may need to install `dos2unix` first.

Comment: There is another bat file that someone else made that runs a script in a different directory.  It executes the code correctly. I copied the exact synthax of that file, however, the bat file that I've made doesn't execute.

Comment: Okay. What do you expect us to do with that information?

Comment: i will try to move the script to a different directory and see if it helps. I don't have anyone to ask so I thought I post this here. Thank you

Comment: The absolute minimum we need is the error message you're getting. Add an error message next time.

Comment: ok, there was a space between `test_scripts` and `perl` that was causing a problem.

Comment: @user3781528 Stop using an editor that inserts DOS-style newlines.